# Automatically find the best autoregressive method

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, statsmodels, arima, autoregressive-models

This is somewhat an abstract question. In Mathematica there is a function [`TimeSeriesModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesModelFit.html) which automatically finds the best autoregressive model fitting the data. Is there a way to do the same in Python? Might it be there is a package for this?

This is the data from Mathematica itself as an example:

```
data = {5., 9., 8., 10., 6.1, 10.4, 9.1, 11.6, 7.5, 12.1, 10.4, 13.5, 
   9., 14.1, 11.9, 15.7, 10.8, 16.4, 13.7, 18.3, 12.9, 19., 15.8, 21.2,
   15.3, 22.1, 18.3, 24.6};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ar_select_order`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ar_select_order.html) can do that:

```
>>> from statsmodels.tsa import ar_model

>>> search = ar_model.ar_select_order(endog=data, maxlag=10, ic="aic", glob=True)
>>> search.ar_lags

array([ 1,  4,  9, 10])
```

It looks up until lag 10; but since `glob` is enabled, it considers *every* 2**10 = 1024 possible lag combinations. Note that this means it doesn't try only 10 models (i.e., AR(1) up to AR(10)), but it turns on and off lags (which is also seen from the above output's discontinous lag suggestion).

`statsmodels` lets you pass these not necessarily continuous lag terms for forming a new model when refitting, e.g.,

```
>>> mod = ar_model.AutoReg(endog=data, lags=[1, 4, 9, 10])
>>> res = mod.fit()
>>> res.aic
-6.380532624300298
```

---

For the models that are not necessarily purely autoregressive, there is [`pmdarima`](http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/index.html) package that implements automatic selection of S-ARIMA-X models. It is based on [`auto.arima`](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i03) of [R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.15/topics/auto.arima). I'm not familiar with ARCH-like models but it seems the [`arch`](https://github.com/bashtage/arch) package's implementation can be wrapped in a loop to try out different models and select with some criterion.

Comment: But doesn't this restrict to only one family member just with various lags? Mathematica seem to do a compehesive search over whole host of models (AR, MA, ARIMA, SARIMA, ARCH, GRACH).

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 From the title and body of the qusetion I thought you werelooking ofr purely autoregressive models. For S-ARIMA-X search, you can look at [pmdarima](http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/index.html). I'm not familiar with ARCH-like models.

Comment: Can you add this to the answer and I will accept it?

Comment: After fitting the model how can I make a simulation with the fitted model. I see that `statsmodel arima` has simulate `attribute`.

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 can you elaborate on what do you exactly mean by simulating?  An example of `simulate` function you mentioned is in the last part of this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/399104/285512 Does that help?

Comment: I mean Monte-Carlo type of simulation of possible paths (time-series), in a sense of new artifical possible scenarios which correctly represent the probabilistic distributions of possible paths.

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 Then the linked answer above seems to do that.